# How to place `library (RgoogleMaps)` inside the code of Rcpp?

Tags: linux, r, rcpp

```
#include "rtest.h"
#include <iostream>

SEXP rcpp_hello_world ()
{
    using namespace Rcpp ;
    CharacterVector x = CharacterVector::create( "foo", "bar" );
    NumericVector y   = NumericVector::create( 0.0, 1.0 );
    List z                   = List::create (x, y);

    return z;
}

void funcA ()
{
    std :: cout << "\nsdfsdfsdf\n";
}

int main () {return 0;}
```

**How to place

`library(RgoogleMaps)`

and

`png (filename="Rg.png", width=480, height=480)`

inside the above code?**

I run it as: `R CMD SHLIB rtest.cpp`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>
```

`Rcpp`'s version is `0.9.13`

**I tried:**
`R CMD SHLIB -lRgoogleMaps rtest.cpp`

It resulted in:

```
anisha@linux-y3pi:~/> R CMD SHLIB -lRgoogleMaps rtest.cpp

g++ -I/usr/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include   -I/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include -fpic  -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables  -c rtest.cpp -o rtest.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o rtest.so rtest.o -lRgoogleMaps -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lRgoogleMaps
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rtest.so] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to do this? **Rcpp** is designed for interfacing C++ code within an R session so that you can exploit faster computation or re-use existing C++ libraries.

Write an R wrapper that calls the Rcpp code, have that wrapper arrange for the package to be made available (using `require(RgoogleMaps)`).

Second, you don't want to hard code the plotting device. Again, you could do this in R:

```
png(filename="Rg.png", width=480, height=480)
##
## call Rcpp function
## in here
dev.off()
```

Rcpp isn't meant for writing standalone C++ applications, you still want to interact with it from an R session.

Comment: ... as when you want to write standalone C++ applications using R as an embedded engine, you would use [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) (which itself uses Rcpp for passing objects around).

Comment: I actually wanted a standalone C++ application using R functionalities.

Comment: Then you actually wanted RInside all along. Check out the numerous examples that comes with it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks Dirk, I will indeed check RInside. I just want a confirmation that besides all, RgoogleMaps "also" can be used with RInside.

Comment: I cannot speak specifically to RGoogleMaps but RInside provides you with a standard R interpreter that you can invoke from your C++ application. So there is no reason why it should not work.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have a bit of a conceptual problem here between what

```
 library(RgoogleMaps)
```

does in R, and what a library is for a compiler

```
 -lfoo -Lpath/to/library
```

The two are not the same, despite the fact that we use the English noun "library" in both cases.

You may need to brush up a little with a text on programming, compilers, linkers, ...

Comment: Dirk, you talked about RInside. Can I use the RgoogleMaps functions inside RInside? How to link the `RgoogleMaps` in `RInside` then? I do need a standalone C++ application which uses R.